# Using DATE_ADD() to obtain the last day of the month

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to create a query that determines if an employee's retirement contribution was made late or on-time. A contribution is late if it is paid later than 30 days after the end of the month in which the employee would have been paid that money otherwise. For example, if an employee was paid on 2022-3-6, then the contribution would have to be made by 2022-4-30. The columns I am working with are:

- `trade_date`: the date the contribution was made
- `pay_date`: the date the employee was paid

I have created the following query, but realized `DATE_ADD(pay_date, interval 1 month)` doesn't work correctly because 2022-3-6 would end up as 2022-4-6 instead of 2022-3-31.

```
 Select trade_date, pay_date,
   CASE WHEN trade_date > DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(pay_date, interval 1 month), interval 30 day) 
        THEN 'Late' ELSE 'On time' END as status
 From 2022_contributions
```

I'm not familiar with a way to add just enough days to get to the end of the month in the inner `DATE_ADD()`. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

I am using MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer but will leave this up in case it helps others. MySQL actually has a function `LAST_DAY()` where you can input your date column and it will return the date of the last day of that month.

Comment: It's good to include a reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day